# Castle ActiveRecord optimistic locking on properties

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, optimistic-locking

Can Castle ActiveRecord do optimistic locking on properties? I found optimistic locking for the entire class, but not for an individual property. In my case, I need to make it so that adding/removing elements in a collection does not update the version number of the entity (so for example, adding a `Product` to a `Store` without changing any of `Store`'s properties will not increment the version number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate supports an `optimistic-lock` property that can be applied to properties or collections and does exactly what you want when set to *false* (default is *true*)

I think ActiveRecord doesn't currently expose it. Not sure how hard it would be to extend it.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty disheartening to hear.

Comment: Well, being open source, it's just a matter of downloading the sources and checking where the mappings are generated. Moving to non-wrapped NHibernate is the next alternative.

Comment: To confirm Diego's answer: ActiveRecord doesn't currently support the optimistic-lock attribute on properties/collections. It's not hard to implement though, see http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Visitors/XmlGenerationVisitor.cs#L598